# Return entire row of dataframe after searching using one entry of said row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

First of - the title is a mess, but I could not think of a better one.

I have a problem to which I am sure a simple solution exists, but I am not able to think of one right now.

I have a dataframe like this. This dataframe I will call "A". There is no system to the numbering of x and y, I just added them to show that there can be duplicates.

| cat0 | cat1 | cat2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x0 | Two | y0 |
| x1 | Seven | y1 |
| x2 | Eight | y2 |
| x3 | Eight | y2 |
| x4 | twelve | y7 |

I then, using the following function, read out which of the words in cat1 is most frequent in a text using max. This then is my subject. I do that for a few thousand texts, each read out from the first page of a pdf.

```
def subject_findall(string):
    
    matches = []

    txt = re.sub(r"[^nA-Za-z-ÖØ-öø-ÿ+]+", "", string).lower()
    txt = re.sub(r"\d", "", txt)

    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        
        searchfor = re.sub(r"[^nA-Za-z-ÖØ-öø-ÿ+]+", "", A["cat1"][i]).lower()
        match = re.findall(searchfor, txt)
        matches.extend(match)
        
        if len(matches) > 0:
            
            subject = max(matches, key = lambda x: matches.count(x))
            
        else:
            
            subject = r"nosubjectfound"
            
    print(subject)    
    return subject
```

This returns the most frequent subject. But I need the information on cat0 and cat2 for the correct subject aswell. It would be best if the function returned a tuple of (subject, cat0ofsubject, cat2 ofsubject).

Is there any way to store the row index with the "searchfor" term? I have tried using a tuple (cat1, index). But iterating over that is not possible with the way I build my function, I would need to iterate over every first tuple item for each tuple in the list. A second idea would be to get the value and with that search through A again, find the correct row and retrieve the needed information from that. I would like to avoid that since it would turn my slow code even slower.

A third option would be to not solve this outside of the function: I can create a df with only the matches and then, based on cat1, merge cat0 and cat2 onto that. This poses another problem: This will create duplicates, since cat1 is not unique. All other variables are also not unique, so if I drop duplicates, I will, inevitably, drop items that should not be dropped.

I hope I was able to adequately describe the problem. Please ask if anything is not clear with what I wrote.

KR

Comment: Do you expect searched words to overlap? Do you need to match partial words (e.g. `one` would match `done`)?

Comment: At this point yes. This poses a few problems in itself, e.g., it labels a book as "economics" even if it is labeled as "healthcare economics" which I have a searchword for aswell. of course it would be perfect If the function would be able to find the most "specific" word. But that one is a) not always the correct one and b) to me seems difficult to code.

Comment: Better provide an example of your text and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and assuming you're not looking for overlapping words, you can greatly simplify your logic to avoid looping over all values.

First craft a single regex, then search for all words a once and use a [`multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) to count and find the most common(s) word(s):

```
import re
from statistics import multimode

def subject_findall(string, df=A):
    s = df['cat1'].str.replace(r"[^nA-Za-z-ÖØ-öø-ÿ+]+", "",
                               regex=True).str.lower()
    words = set(s)
    regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, words))
    top = multimode(re.findall(regex, string.lower()))
    if not top:
        return 'nosubjectfound'
    else:
        print(f'most common: {", ".join(top)}')
        return df[s.isin(top)]

text = 'This is an example with Seven Two Seven and Eight Eight.'
out = subject_findall(text)
```

Print:

```
most common: seven, eight
```

Output:

```
  cat0   cat1 cat2
1   x1  Seven   y1
2   x2  Eight   y2
3   x3  Eight   y2
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. I will get back to once I find the time to test this out. Thank you in advance!